# How will they charge me for exchanging Colombian currency?

Tags: exchange, colombia

I will be traveling to Colombia next month and I'd like to know how they will charge me.

By this I mean that if the exchange rate is approximately 1 USD = 3000 COP, will the charge it as 3000 COP or will they deduct some money from it?

I ask this because when I send money through Western Union, if the exchange rate is 1 USD = 3000 COP they actually charge it as 2900 COP.

Comment: The OP wants to know if the provider will gross up or net down.

Comment: @GayotFow who is the provider?  It's not even clear that she isn't talking about some other kind of company.

Answer (score 2):

According to **[XE.com](http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?From=USD&To=COP)**, today's exchange rate is 1 USD =3,117.01COP

An American expat living in Medellin has this to offer on [**where to get the best exchange rates**](http://medellinliving.com/colombian-currency-counterfeits-exchanging-money/). The full article also has very useful information on counterfeit currency (how to identify and avoid).

> **Exchanging Money**
>
> You can use ATMs, banks or money exchange places (casas de cambio) to get Colombian currency.
>
> With ATMs you will usually get the best exchange rate. ATMs are plentiful in Colombia with several normally found in each mall. They are also found in many locations on the streets.
>
> However, be careful of using ATMs located on the street; it is safer to use ATMs inside a mall.
>
> At Medellín’s José María Córdova International Airport you will find ATM machines on the level with the airline check-in desks.
>
> For exchanging currency, casas de cambio sometimes offer slightly better rates than banks and have more flexible hours plus provide quicker service. You can find casas de cambio in many of the malls in Colombia.
>
> You will need a passport or cédula (Colombian ID) to exchange money in a casa de cambio or bank in Colombia.
>
> A few times in the past I have seen casas de cambio with exchange rates slightly better than the rate found on xe.com. But this hasn’t been the case recently with the strong dollar.

Answer (score 0):

The current exchange is about 1 USD = 2915.6447 COP at Western Union.

If you pay by debit or credit card, the fee is about $20; and if you pay with "Bank account" (don't know what this is), the fee is $8 (but takes some days).

Have a look at it : 
https://www.westernunion.com/us/en/price-estimator/continue.html